# Thunar is unable to mount/unmount partitions correctly

Tags: mount, fstab, thunar, policykit

I've got a "NTFS" partition on my Ubuntu machine which I use it to share files between my Ubuntu and Windows.

The problem is that I'm not able to `mount` it using my file manager, the error is:

- *Not authorized to perform operation.*

So I edited the `/etc/fstab` file to mount this partition automatically at the boot time. Now, it's mounted however I'm not able to `unmount` it using my file manager.

`/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[partition uuid]     /media/d       ntfs-3g       defaults        0       0
```

What should I do to be able `mount` and `unmount` this partition as a normal user from GUI?

- I'm using "Thunar" as my file manager, and
- I'm running "OpenBox" on my Ubuntu (It's a minimal installation).

Comment: Are you running thunar as root? What if you don't add the mount to fstab; can you then mount/unmount in thunar without running it as root?

Comment: Answer to both questions is no. Problem was related to session doesn't have an authentication agent... it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a "polkit authentication agent" installed and it's running, I use `policykit-1-gnome`:

```
sudo apt install policykit-1-gnome
```

After installing it, add this line:

```
/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &
```

to your autostart file:

```
~/.config/openbox/autostart
```

Also remove your partition line from `/etc/fstab`, you don't need it anymore.

Now we should create a rule to allow mounting without requiring password:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udisks.pkla
```

And add these:

```
[udisks2]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system;
ResultActive=yes
```

You can change `sudo` with an other groups like: `disk`, `storage` or whatever, I like to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thunar did not mount the partition at `/media/d`. Since you have added the line in `fstab` with `defaults` option, root performed the activity and hence only root user has the permission to unmount it.

to unmount it, you need to run the below command

```
sudo umount /media/d
```